# fs.readFile Behaving Differently Inside Docker Container

Tags: node.js, docker, async-await, fs

The following code has never failed when run in dev on OSX, but fails every time in a production environment which lives in a Docker container:

**DataSyncController.js**

```
let jsonFile = await FileSystemService.ParseCsvToJson(fileName);
if (!jsonFile.success)
        return res.json({ success: false });

let parsedJson = await FileSystemService.ParseJsonFile({ file: jsonFile.fileName });
if (!parsedJson.success)
    return res.json({ success: false });
```

**FileSystemService.js**

```
static async ParseJsonFile(params)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        try
        {
            fs.readFile(jsonFilePath, 'utf-8', (err, data) =>
            {
                if (err)
                {
                    console.log('fs.readFile() error: ', err);
                    resolve({ success: false });
                }

                var file = [];

                try
                {
                    // This fails every time in the Docker container
                    // Error is [Unexpected end of input]
                    // At this point I've seend `data` evaluate to '',
                    // <buffer >, undefined and partial JSON data
                    file = JSON.parse(data);
                }
                catch(e)
                {
                    console.log('ERROR parsing JSON file: ', e);
                    return resolve({ success: false });
                }

                // Do Stuff
                return resolve({ success: true });
            });
        }
        catch(exception)
        {
            console.error(exception);
            resolve({ success: false });
        }
    });
}
```

It seems like in the Docker container the JSON file is not done being written by the time it's read (e.g., that `JSON.parse()` works if I put the whole `fs.readFile()` block in a `timeout` and prevent it from running for 5 seconds), but I don't see how that's possible, nor why it would be the case in the Docker container and not on my local machine. Any thoughts are, as always, much appreciated.

**Update**

As requested, here is the implementation of the `ParseCsvToJson` method which actually writes the JSON file to disk. Note that both in dev and production in the Docker container, the written JSON file, while large (around 4,400 records), looks fine.

```
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var filePath = `${config.root}/server/uploadDir`;

static async ParseCsvToJson(fileName)
{
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    {
        try
        {
            let fileNameWithoutExtension = fileName.replace('.csv', '');
            const jsonFilePath = `${filePath}/${fileNameWithoutExtension}.json`;
            const csvFilePath = `${filePath}/${fileName}`;

            // The parameter false will turn off final result construction.
            // It can avoid huge memory consumption while parsing.
            // The trade off is final result will not be populated to end_parsed event.
            var csvConverter = new Converter({ constructResult: false, toArrayString: true });
            var readStream = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath);
            var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(jsonFilePath);
            readStream.pipe(csvConverter).pipe(writeStream);

            resolve({ success: true, fileName: `${fileNameWithoutExtension}.json` });
        }
        catch(exception)
        {
            console.error(exception);
            resolve({ success: false });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `ParseJsonFile()` function should reject, instead of resolving with "success = false".

Comment: Yeah, that's actually on my list to change. I had a reason for doing it that way, but I honestly don't remember what that was at the moment.

Comment: Show the implementation of `ParseCsvToJson`, too. (I take it that this one, in spite of its quirky name, actually writes the JSON file, so I suspect the error there)

Comment: @Tomalak: I added the requested code.

Comment: Yup, I'm pretty sure that that's the problem. Don't resolve with "status = false", simply reject instead.

Comment: Ah, now I remember why I was only resolving. When I reject, the function never returns. It just hangs on that `catch` block.

Comment: And *that's* the question you should actually be asking, this one here is a red herring. Make an abstract, minimal sample of two async functions that reproduces the situation (in a new question).

Comment: So, wrapping the calls to `FileSystemService` in try/catch blocks causes the promises to resolve/reject properly. There are still a lot of whys here obviously, but yeah, that's an entirely different question . Thanks!

Comment: However, I just did a prod build and still have the same `Unexpected end of input` error in the Docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the instantiation of the converter:

```
var csvConverter = new Converter({ constructResult: false, toArrayString: true });
```

The docs say:

> The parameter false will turn off final result construction.
> It can avoid huge memory consumption while parsing.
> The trade off is final result will not be populated to end_parsed event.

For reasons I do not really understand, on OSX, this is sufficient:

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/csvfile.csv', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('path/to/jsonfile.json', { encoding: 'utf-8' });
readStream.pipe(csvConverter).pipe(writeStream);
resolve({ success: true, fileName: '.json' });
```

Whereas, on a Linux system, the file is not always completely written, or written at all. Therefore, the following is also required:

```
csvConverter.on('end_parsed', () =>
{
    // The docs are unclear whether there is a possible error object
    // passed along here in the case of failure, but clearly mention 
    // that the constructed result will be unavailable, so just resolve 
    // the Promise
    resolve({ success: true, fileName: 'jsonfile.json' });
});
```

This may be a fringe case, but hopefully it'll help someone else in the future.